# SQL - Convert varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Any way to convert this varchar -> "18-Jan-2015 12:43:51" to datetime in SQL database?
Thanks.

Comment: a little googling might help. if you have tried something please provide the code and error

Answer (score 0):

Use [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with [`replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
Select convert(datetime, replace('18-Jan-2015 12:43:51', '-', ' '), 113)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('18-Jan-2015 12:43:51',23),101))
```

Comment: SELECT (CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('18-Jan-2015 12:43:51',23),101)). this is working in sql server 2012.. the result I got : 2015-01-18 12:43:51.000.  I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use statement like below

```
Select convert(datetime, replace('18-Jan-2015 12:43:51', '-', ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST('18-Jan-2015 12:43:51' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like everybody said above, the best way to do it is either with convert or cast, besides, this is very basic sql

here are both cases:

```
SELECT CAST('18-Jan-2015 12:43:51' AS DATETIME) AS DATE

SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, REPLACE('18-Jan-2015 12:43:51', '-', ' '))
```